# Libreoffice: extract image from object

Tags: libreoffice

I have been given a docx file from which I am trying to extract images with Libreoffice. With actual "Image" elements in the file it is easy (right-click->Save). But there are also "Object" elements for which a right-click does not offer "Save". I tried the trick described here: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-can-i-extract-photos-from-a-doc-text-document/9095 but the corresponding files in the zip are not images: they are called Obj102 and Obj103 and have no filename extension. The linux "file" command tells

```
Composite Document File V2 Document, Cannot read section info
```

Using a hex tool to look at the bytes in the file, I found it embeds a BMP file. Removing all bytes before the "BM" tag in the hex dump, I managed to get the image.

This is a hack, time consuming and clumsy. Ought there not be a way to do it directly from Libreoffice?

Comment: Is there no "Save copy as" right click option like I see for embedded equations and documents?

Comment: @vanadium nope...

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice ODT documents are in fact zip archives with fixed structure inside. What you could do is:

1. open your DOCX document with LibreOffice and save/export DOCX as ODT
2. rename ODT to ZIP
3. open ZIP with your archive manager
4. find all embedded images in the Pictures sub-folder

Step 2 may not be necessary as the archive manager may simply be able to open ODT as is.

Recent DOCX formats are also internally ZIP files, so the same approach may apply to those documents as well.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot remember which files these were (post is 1yr old), so I cannot try your solution right away, but if the problem appears again, I'll see if it works.